# Find substring only in a line

Tags: regex, unix

I have a <strike>text</strike> binary file with several thousand lines made up of lines that consist of dates and words. Most of these lines contain the word REGULAR. However, there is a corrupt line somewhere in the file that just contains REGU.

Is there a way where I can just isolate the line number with the word REGU?

Example line

*BLLAH2014-02-26REGULAR2014-01-02-20.06.03BLAHHHH*

Comment: Example for corrupt line?

Comment: That is the problem, I don't know where the corrupt line is, so can't tell you what it looks like

Comment: *binary* and *line numbers* don't make any sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -anw  "REGU[^L]*" file.bin
```

With this command you can find all the lines which match `REGU` followed by any character distinct of `L` or none

---

### Explanation

#### grep options

The long option format of `-anw` is:

`--text --line-number --word-regexp`

```
--text
```

Due to your file is a binary, you must add `-a` to force `grep` to interpret that file as if it were text.

```
--line-number
```

It prints the line number of the matched *text*. It satisfies your requirement.

```
--word-regexp
```

This option excludes any match starting with `REGUL` (i.e.: `REGULAR`)

Answer (score 1):

As you dont know the corrupt lines, first find the lines that are not `REGULAR` and then find those `REGU` lines.

Also you are searching binary files. hence the `-a` option

```
 grep -nva REGULAR file.txt | grep -a REGU
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below Perl command,

```
perl -nle 'print $. if /(?<![a-zA-Z])REGU(?![A-Za-z])/' file
```